# CSS hover effect for PNG images

Tags: html, css, image, webkit, hover

I need a CSS hover effect for a png image without using two images.  Bascially when a user hovers over the png image it would show a glow or other effect without highlighting the whole box but just the png image.  I've tried using masking effect but that requires a second image and i have multiple object that don't have same shape and I want to use one css effect for all.

HTML

```
<div class="brighten pic">
    <img src="imgs/bookcase-02.png">
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*DARKEN*/
.brighten img {
display: inline-block;
margin: 100px auto;
-webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}
.brighten img:hover {
-webkit-filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

Comment: *I need a CSS hover effect for a png* Ordering us won't help you get the codes, try it first, post some code and you will get some help

Comment: change opacity of image on hover.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
.brighten img {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.brighten img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the feedback.  I actually don't want the image be faded I want the image to have 100% opacity at all times but have 20% brightness on the hover.  Also Is it possible to have only the PNG be highlighted without the backgound.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this in JQuery. Be sure you are calling the JQuery library. I call mine from google:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

THEN you want to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".YourImageName").mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 2px #888');
        });
        $(".YourImageName").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).css('box-shadow', 'none');
        });
    }
</script>
```

This gives you a shadow around the edges and you can change the color or change the css entirely to better suit your needs.

It would be a little more helpful in the future if you provided us what code you currently have so we have a better understanding of what it is you want. This code is taken from live web use and changed to work for your scenario. You will have to change the class names to yours. Hope this helps!